# remote_function and select boxes in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, onchange

I have a select box that
needs to submit it's value to a server side controller on change.

The submit works. The value of the changed element is however not sent.

I've scoured some examples online, but none seem to work

```
 remote_function(
     :url => some_remote_function_path,
     :with => "'key1='+$('elem_id').value +'&key2='+$('elem_id').value+ '&this_elem_value='+value"
  )
```

The moment I pass

```
$('elem_id').value
```

I simply get that 'statically' as the actual variable passed.

How do I get access to the selected select box value? I'm sure I'm missing something minute her.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [jQuery.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) not `.value`.

Comment: What does remote_function use by default?

Could I have jQuery prototype clashes?

Comment: I still get 


  Parameters: {"update_grid_item"=>"0,0", "action"=>"pair", "authenticity_token"=>"AFgY2E7kY2PcPx5XrFWFtYRpcObdQty4THs2et6RyRU=", "id"=>"1", "controller"=>"impact", "_"=>"", "with"=>"'value=' + jQuery.val()"}

It seems like it is not interpreted or called but passed statically as text.

Comment: <select id="drop_0_0" name="drop_0,0" onchange="new Ajax.Request('/impact_matrix/pair/1?update_grid_item=0%2C0&amp;with=%27value%3D%27%2B%24%28%27elem_id%27%29.val%28%29', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('AFgY2E7kY2PcPx5XrFWFtYRpcObdQty4THs2et6RyRU=')})"><option value="y">Yes</option> 

is what is generated.

Comment: the JS is encoded, and therefore the value goes missing or is accessed incorrectly. How should I modify this?

Comment: Problem was actually a prototype, jQuery conflict.